# Select features in feature collection where two properties are equal in Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I feel like I am missing something basic here. I am looking to select only the features within a feature collection that have matching property values.

For example I would like to only select the second row where both fields have the exact same date (2019-08-09):

| Field1date | Field2date |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-08 |
| 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 |
| 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-10 |
| 2019-08-10 | 2019-08-08 |
| 2019-08-10 | 2019-08-09 |

If I export the feature collection from GEE to a .csv file I can do this simply with R with the following function:

`datSelect<-data[data$Field1date==data$Field2date, ]`

It would be great to do this before my Export.table.toDrive in GEE.  I have tried with:

`var datSelect = data.filterMetadata('Field1date', 'equals', 'Field2date');`

But it returns zero elements.

Comment: I edited my answer to fit your clarified question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing field to field, you use the leftField, rightField arguments in ee.Filter.equals.  (Also, you should basically never use filterMetadata)

```
data.filter(ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'Field1date', rightField: 'Field2date'})
```

Comment: Thank you Noel!!! works as advertised and thanks for the tip on filterMetadata.  The line now reads in GEE:                                
 var datSelect = data.filter(ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'Field1date', rightField: 'Field2date'}))

Comment: Is `filterMetadata()` inherently inefficient? or only in this case?

Comment: It's only equivalent to one combination (leftField+rightValue), and it's always longer (more typing) than the other options (ie: filter('property == value'), even if that's all you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Though not quite as easy as in R, but I understand better what you are trying to do.

There might be an easier way to do it, but this is the only way I can think of doing it.

First you will have to go through a function that will check if each feature has the same value in both properties and set a new property with the result of that check (Pass or Fail).  Here we will find the difference between the 2 dates (and you may have to add the `ee.Date()` so that it knows it is dealing with a date).  If the difference is `0` then earth engine will go to the second part of the `ee.Algorithms.If()` (making it pass). If the difference is not `0` then it will go to the first part.

The result is you will have a featureCollection that has a new property added `Pass` that will either have a value of `Yes` or `No`.

From that you simply `filterMetadata()` to the value you are interested in.  So now `onlyEqualDates` will contain the features that meet your criteria.

```
var onlyEqualDates = data.map(function(feature){
  return ee.Algorithms.If(feature.getDate("Field1date").difference(feature.getDate("Field2date"),"day"),
                          feature.set("Pass", "No"),
                          feature.set("Pass","Yes"))})
                  .filterMetadata("Pass","equals","Yes");
```